# PHP, need to genrate PPT file using PhpOffice\PhpPresentation library. My question is is that possible to generate file using default template?

Tags: php, powerpoint

Need to generate PPT in PHP using PhpOffice\PhpPresentation library.

I can able to generate files using text.

Below mentioned my questions:

1. Is that possible to generate using template or image as background?
2. How to generate HTML content like tables and set background color.

Below mentioned my current code for your reference.

```
<?php
                require 'vendor/autoload.php';

                use PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\PhpPresentation;
                use PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\IOFactory;

                // Create a new presentation
                $presentation = new PhpPresentation();

                // Add the first slide
                $firstSlide = $presentation->getActiveSlide();

                // Set the slide background color (optional)
                $backgroundShape = $firstSlide->createRichTextShape();
                $backgroundShape->setHeight(720);
                $backgroundShape->setWidth(960);
                $backgroundShape->getActiveParagraph()->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(\PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\Style\Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
                $backgroundShape->getActiveParagraph()->getAlignment()->setVertical(\PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\Style\Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER);
                $backgroundShape->getFill()->setFillType(\PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\Style\Fill::FILL_SOLID);
                $backgroundShape->getFill()->getStartColor()->setRGB('FFFFFF');

                // Add dynamic content to the first slide
                $textShape = $firstSlide->createRichTextShape();
                $textShape->setHeight(300);
                $textShape->setWidth(600);
                $textShape->setOffsetX(220);
                $textShape->setOffsetY(60);

                // Add a text run to the shape
                $textRun = $textShape->createTextRun('WELCOME TO');
                $textRun->getFont()->setSize(48);
                $textRun->getFont()->setBold(true);
                $textRun->getFont()->setColor(new \PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\Style\Color('00000'));

                $imagePath = 'bnilogo.png';
                $shape = $firstSlide->createDrawingShape();
                $shape->setName('Image');
                $shape->setDescription('Image Description');
                $shape->setPath($imagePath);
                $shape->setWidth(300);
                $shape->setHeight(150);
                $shape->setOffsetX(300);
                $shape->setOffsetY(200);


                // Add the second slide
                $secondSlide = $presentation->createSlide();

                // Set the slide background color (optional)
                $backgroundShape = $secondSlide->createRichTextShape();
                $backgroundShape->setHeight(720);
                $backgroundShape->setWidth(960);
                $backgroundShape->getActiveParagraph()->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(\PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\Style\Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
                $backgroundShape->getActiveParagraph()->getAlignment()->setVertical(\PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\Style\Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER);
                $backgroundShape->getFill()->setFillType(\PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\Style\Fill::FILL_SOLID);
                $backgroundShape->getFill()->getStartColor()->setRGB('FF5733');

                // Add dynamic content to the second slide
                $textShape = $secondSlide->createRichTextShape();
                $textShape->setHeight(300);
                $textShape->setWidth(600);
                $textShape->setOffsetX(180);
                $textShape->setOffsetY(150);

                // Add a text run to the shape
                $htmlcontent = "WELCOME TO PHP WORLD";
                //$textRun = $textShape->createTextRun($htmlcontent);

                $textRun = $textShape->createTextRun('Dynamic Text with Styles');
                //$textRun->getFont()->setSize(28);
                $textRun->getFont()->setBold(true);
                //$textRun->getFont()->setColor(new \PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\Style\Color('FF5733'));
                $textRun->getFont()->setItalic(true);
                $textRun->getFont()->setUnderline(true);
                $textRun->getFont()->setStrikethrough(true);
                $textRun->getFont()->setName('Arial');

                 $textRun->getFont()->setSize(48);
                 $textRun->getFont()->setColor(new \PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\Style\Color('FFFFFF'));

                // Add the third slide
                $thirdSlide = $presentation->createSlide();

                // Set the slide background color (optional)
                $backgroundShape = $thirdSlide->createRichTextShape();
                $backgroundShape->setHeight(720);
                $backgroundShape->setWidth(960);
                $backgroundShape->getActiveParagraph()->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(\PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\Style\Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
                $backgroundShape->getActiveParagraph()->getAlignment()->setVertical(\PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\Style\Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER);
                $backgroundShape->getFill()->setFillType(\PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\Style\Fill::FILL_SOLID);
                $backgroundShape->getFill()->getStartColor()->setRGB('33FF57');

                // Add dynamic content to the third slide
                $textShape = $thirdSlide->createRichTextShape();
                $textShape->setHeight(300);
                $textShape->setWidth(600);
                $textShape->setOffsetX(180);
                $textShape->setOffsetY(150);

                // Add a text run to the shape
                $textRun = $textShape->createTextRun('Dynamic Text on the Third Slide');
                $textRun->getFont()->setSize(48);
                $textRun->getFont()->setColor(new \PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\Style\Color('FFFFFF'));

                // Add more slides with dynamic content (optional)
                $fourthSlide = $presentation->createSlide();

                // Set the slide background color (optional)
                $backgroundShape = $fourthSlide->createRichTextShape();
                $backgroundShape->setHeight(720);
                $backgroundShape->setWidth(960);
                $backgroundShape->getActiveParagraph()->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(\PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\Style\Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
                $backgroundShape->getActiveParagraph()->getAlignment()->setVertical(\PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\Style\Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER);
                $backgroundShape->getFill()->setFillType(\PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\Style\Fill::FILL_SOLID);
                $backgroundShape->getFill()->getStartColor()->setRGB('33FF57');

                // Add dynamic content to the third slide
                $textShape = $fourthSlide->createRichTextShape();
                $textShape->setHeight(300);
                $textShape->setWidth(600);
                $textShape->setOffsetX(180);
                $textShape->setOffsetY(150);

                // Add a text run to the shape
                $textRun = $textShape->createTextRun('Dynamic Text on the fourth Slide');
                $textRun->getFont()->setSize(48);
                $textRun->getFont()->setColor(new \PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\Style  \Color('FFFFFF'));


                // Add dynamic content to the fourth slide and continue the process for more slides...

                // Save the presentation
                $dynamicPresentationPath = 'dynamic_presentation.pptx';
                $objWriter = IOFactory::createWriter($presentation, 'PowerPoint2007');
                $objWriter->save($dynamicPresentationPath);

                echo "Dynamic PowerPoint presentation generated successfully!";
```

I have attached the my expecting output for your reference.

[image]

Need ability to generate PPT using the background image or ppt file with HTML content like table and charts

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `PhpOffice\PhpPresentation` library along with the `PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\Style` classes.

e.g.

Add a Template or Image as a Background.

```
// your image file
$imagePath = 'path/to/background_image.jpg';

// Set the background image for the first slide
$backgroundImage = $firstSlide->createDrawingShape();
$backgroundImage->setPath($imagePath);
$backgroundImage->setWidth(960);
$backgroundImage->setHeight(720);
$backgroundImage->setOffsetX(0);
$backgroundImage->setOffsetY(0);
```

Generate HTML-Like Content with Tables and Background Color.

```
// Add a new slide
$newSlide = $presentation->createSlide();

// Set the slide background color (optional)
$backgroundShape = $newSlide->createRichTextShape();
$backgroundShape->setHeight(720);
$backgroundShape->setWidth(960);
$backgroundShape->getFill()->setFillType(\PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\Style\Fill::FILL_SOLID);
$backgroundShape->getFill()->getStartColor()->setRGB('FF5733');

// Create a table
$table = $newSlide->createTable();

// Set the column widths
$table->getColumnWidth(0)->setWidth(200);
$table->getColumnWidth(1)->setWidth(200);
$table->getColumnWidth(2)->setWidth(200);

// Add rows and cells with background colors
$row = $table->addRow();
$row->getFill()->setFillType(\PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\Style\Fill::FILL_SOLID);
$row->getFill()->getStartColor()->setRGB('FFFFFF');
$row->getCell(0)->setText('Cell 1');
$row->getCell(1)->setText('Cell 2');
$row->getCell(2)->setText('Cell 3');

$row = $table->addRow();
$row->getFill()->setFillType(\PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\Style\Fill::FILL_SOLID);
$row->getFill()->getStartColor()->setRGB('ECECEC');
$row->getCell(0)->setText('Cell 4');
$row->getCell(1)->setText('Cell 5');
$row->getCell(2)->setText('Cell 6');

// Continue adding more rows and cells as needed

// Style the table cells' text
foreach ($table->getRows() as $row) {
    foreach ($row->getCells() as $cell) {
        $cell->getTextRun()->getFont()->setSize(12);
        $cell->getTextRun()->getFont()->setColor(new \PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\Style\Color('000000'));
    }
}
```

Note that to set an image as the background for a slide, you can use the `createDrawingShape()` method and set the image path as the background of the slide. Make sure to add this code before adding any other content to the slide. And to create content like tables with background colors, you can utilize the `Table` class and the style properties for text and cells.